# is there clang alternative to gcc's -s flag?

Tags: gcc, clang, clang++

I am trying to find an -s flag alternative for clang. The s strips all symbols in file, which results in extremely small files. (from 300 kb to 18 in basic hello world). the problem is, that clang gives me 320 KB file, because I can't find any -s alternative. Is there any?

Comment: Can't you just use `strip`?

Comment: What do you mean by that? like binutills strip?

Comment: [strip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html) strip